# How to add property into object in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to add a custom response in Express JS, like add an attribute that not exists in the database?

My Controller:

```
createNewPersonalData: function (req, res) {
var name = req.body.name,
    date_of_birth = req.body.date_of_birth;

var getAge = function () {
    var today = new Date();
            var dob = new Date(date_of_birth);
            var count = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - dob.getMonth();
            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                count = count - 1;
            }

            return count;
        };
    PersonalInfo.create({
        name : name,
        date_of_birth : date_of_birth,
        age : getAge()
        }).then(data => {
           res.json({
                'status': 'OK',
                'messages': 'Personal Info Created',
                'data': data
            })
        });
```

but the response is only all attribute from the database table. There's no attribute/field `age`.

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "date_of_birth": "1995-01-28T17:00:00.000Z",
    }
}
```

the response what I expected is like:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "date_of_birth": "1995-01-28T17:00:00.000Z",
        "age": 24
    }
}
```

How do I can add that `age`?

Comment: yes you can, can you also show what `getAge()` contains?

Comment: contain? that you mean the result? if that what you mean, the result is an int, like "42". It's come from `curren_date - date_of_birth` and convert into years

Comment: It is easy if you are using some kind of high level database frameworks. For example on mongoose you could use post middleware or virtual fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `age` property to the data object after converting it to a JSON object with the `toJSON` function in the Promise response.

```
PersonalInfo.create({
    name : name,
    date_of_birth : date_of_birth,
    //age : getAge()
}).then(data => {
    var info = data.toJSON({ versionKey:false });
    info['age'] = getAge();
    res.json({
      'code':200,
      'status': 'OK',
      'messages': 'Personal Info Created',
      'data': info
    })
});
```

Comment: It's work in method post for create data, but how if we want to getAll data? The data response should be a list of array.

Comment: getAll data as in a list of all PersonalInfo ?

Comment: Yes, I mean how if I do method get to get All data, the result should be an array or list.

Comment: I've tried, but this didn't work. I think it because the Var Data Format. I've update the question with Var Data Format example added

Comment: I don't understand what 'Var Data Format' means ? Can you show what output do you expect exactly ?

Comment: the result of method PersonalInfo.create has type Object. And variable data format I mean the type and the example

Comment: what database and library are you using?

Comment: Answer depends on what are you using. For example on mongoose you could use post middleware or virtual fields.

Comment: @Enxtur I'm using Mysql and library sequelize

Comment: @Blackjack There is type named VIRTUAL on sequelizejs. I think it is better to do calculation code in schema once, not in all other handlers. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/data-types.js~VIRTUAL.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you said using sequelize.js, you can use DataTypes.VIRTUAL on schema. And there is nothing you need to do in handlers for age calculation.

```js
sequelize.define('PersonalInfo', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  date_of_birth: DataTypes.DATE
  age: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get: function() {
      return getAge(this.get('date_of_birth'))
    }
  }
})
```